# how to recalculate outer div height in jquery

Tags: jquery

See below. Imagine #inner content grew. Using Jquery how can i make the outer div recalculate its height so that it should all of the inner content. The overflow is required.

```
<div id="outer" style="height:100px; overflow:hidden;">

<div id="inner">

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this may helps u

#### [jQuery.outerHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/)

---

> **Get the current computed  height for the first element in the
>   set of matched elements, including padding, border, and optionally margin.**

to **include margin** write `true` inside function like below :

```
        $('#outer').outerHeight(true);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uUGvL/1)

Comment: thanks, but what if #inner now had a height of 200px, i need a way to get the height of the whole outer. I guess i'm getting tripped up by the overflow.

Answer (score 1):

try to get the height of the inner after grow and set the outer with that

```
var h =$("#inner").height();
$("#outer").height(h);
```

Comment: This will exclude padding, margin and border width. `outerHeight` is the way to go.